# How to check a subfolder existence VB6

Tags: vb6

Ive been searching for this for like decades with no success.
I need to find out if a subdfolder that i ve given the name is exist..

```
For i = 0 To 3 'got 4 different loc to check sub folders
    Set f = fso.GetFolder(backupdir(i)) 
    Set sf = f.SubFolders
    For Each fr In sf 'for each folder in sub folder
        Do Until fr = "" Or fr = Null 
            If fso.FolderExists(fr.SubFolders) Then 
            'if more sub folders exist i wanna make sure
            'that i can get their subfolders too
            'till there is no sub folder left..
                sf = fr
            End If
        Loop
    Next fr
Next i
```

Comment: Looks like you after a *recursive* search, take a look @ http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/fileapi/recursive.htm

Comment: this is really usefull but can u explain the part where i can include specific path to search. like "\\blabla\Afolder\ThefolderIsearchFor\AnotherFolder"

Comment: Woops sorry, that link was not the one I intended. You need to open it & click *FindFirstFile: Recursive Search for Folders Using a Folder Mask (minimal code)* under *Related*

Comment: yea i already found that so about recursive search i wasnt even sure what it is till now ty for solution its really usefull but u sould post this as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actions like traversing the folders-of-a-folder-of-a-folder... is called *recursing*.

The *FindFirstFile: Recursive Search for Folders Using a Folder Mask (minimal code)* example [here](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/fileapi/recursive.htm) shows how to do this quickly with the windows API.

Answer (score 2):

Check this code.

```
Dim FolderList As String

Private Sub SubCheck1(folderToCheck As String)
   Dim fso, f, f1, s, sf
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set f = fso.GetFolder(folderToCheck)
   Set sf = f.SubFolders
   For Each f1 In sf
      FolderList = FolderList & "|" & f1.Name
      Call SubCheck1(f1.Path)
   Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Call SubCheck1("c:\folderToSearch")
   Debug.Print FolderList
End Sub
```

This code gets all the subfolders in the specified directory(c:\folderToSearch in this case) and writes them into the string FolderList with a "|" seperator.

You can also use an array instead of separating folder names with a "|".
Or you can add the code below after the `Debug.Print FolderList` line in `Form_Load` to get an array:

```
myArray = split(FolderList, "|")
```

Comment: this is easier way to do it but slower than @wqw way of coding. ty for this answer, its really good for a new starter like me to unsderstand.

Comment: If you have a lot of subfolders under your subfolders, you can add `DoEvents` command under For Loop's in both SubCheck subs in order for your program to response.

Answer (score 1):

You can "recurse" subfolders with a collection and standard `Dir` function in 20 lines of code like this

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim vElem           As Variant

    For Each vElem In pvGetFolders("C:\TEMP")
        Debug.Print vElem
    Next
End Sub

Private Function pvGetFolders(ByVal sRoot As String) As Collection
    Dim lIdx            As Long
    Dim sFile           As String

    Set pvGetFolders = New Collection
    pvGetFolders.Add sRoot
    Do While lIdx < pvGetFolders.Count
        lIdx = lIdx + 1
        sFile = Dir(pvGetFolders.Item(lIdx) & "\*.*", vbDirectory)
        Do While LenB(sFile) <> 0
            If sFile <> "." And sFile <> ".." Then
                sFile = pvGetFolders.Item(lIdx) & "\" & sFile
                If (GetAttr(sFile) And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
                    pvGetFolders.Add sFile
                End If
            End If
            sFile = Dir
        Loop
    Loop
    pvGetFolders.Remove 1
End Function
```

Comment: very nice one really liked the way of usage.

Answer (score 0):

You could use WMI. You could search in CIM_Directory, I believe the field name is "name",
and if it contains the folder or partially the foldername you are looking for, return the full name.

Comment: can u post a link to it? i already solved it with the help of @Alex K. but wanna see other options as well.